# Android Toolbar back button position

Tags: android, toolbar

I have a layout with ToolBar which has a close/back icon. Now I have created an another layout which is transparent and on top of previous layout. This layover layout also has a close/back icon.

I need to align this icon EXACTLY on top of the icon beneath. Is there anyway to find the margins/paddings for this?

Comment: It is the *Up* (sometimes close) button / navigation, the actual back button could show a different behavior

Comment: I agree. Actually I am using an another image (cross icon) and that could be the reason I couldn't align it using the default 16dp padding. Anyways I got it fixed by adding another ToolBar in the overlay fragment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can look material design doc. https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar

App bar height: 56dp
App bar left and right padding: 16dp
App bar icon top, bottom, left padding: 16dp
App bar title left padding: 72dp
App bar title bottom padding: 20dp

Comment: This was a nice direction setter but didn't work. Actually it is a bit complex than that.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this is having another ToolBar in the overlay fragment. In this way you can get icons exactly on top of other icon without doing any dirty work. 
At least that's how I resolved my issue.